# What's the difference between withStyle and withTheme in material ui?

Tags: material-ui

I am new to the web development, and I am trying to use material-ui.  I saw some demo codes use withStyle and some others use withTheme.  Are there any differences between them? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the accepted answer is not well-explained, to be more clear:

1) `withStyles` also provides the `theme` object when creating css styles; the signature of creating function is like:

```
const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    maxWidth: 600,
  },
  tabs: {
    borderTopWidth: 1,
    borderTopStyle: 'solid',
    borderColor: theme.palette.divider,
    width: '100%',
  },
});
```

As one can see `theme` and everything inside it like `theme.palette` can be accessed. Official documentation and examples are everywhere so I just randomly picked [this one](https://material-ui.com/demos/buttons/#floating-action-buttons). (Press this button to show the source codes: "< >")

2) The purpose of `withTheme` is to inject `theme` into `props`, so it could also be accessed inside component functions like `render`, sometimes it's useful. Official documentation [here](https://material-ui.com/customization/themes/#withtheme-component-component).

Answer (score 1):

`withStyles` overrides the style of a specific component.

`withTheme` overrides the style of a specific component while also giving you access to the theme so that your style can be based on the theme's colors, typography, spacing, etc.

It can be confusing because you have to create a new component using these higher-order functions:

```
const MyCustomBottom = withStyles(styles)(Button);
const MyCustomThemeBasedButton = withTheme(theme)(Button);
```